# rails in production mode doesn't render index.html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, production

I tried my application in production mode and the index.html file in my public folder doesn't get rendered, I'm getting a `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/"):` error.

The index.html File is rendered properly in development and test environment. How could this be?

Comment: have you a webserver in front of your app ? Have you activate the static render ?

Comment: thats it, i didn't have a real webserver, just the webrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by putting rails into a real webserver like apache, because rails in production mode will never serve static content.